# 'No data exists for the row/column.' Oledb Exception

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Names] FROM Test", 
connection);

OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
string result = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
        connection.Close();
```

Could anyone help? I'm getting 'No data exists for the row/column.' this error thrown

Comment: That happens when no data exists or you fail to `reader.Read` before trying to fish data out of a data reader.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling Read Method

```
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
    {
       string result = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
       MessageBox.Show(result);
     }
    connection.Close();
```

This will just read the first row from the result.If you want all the rows then you will need to write some thing like this

```
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();        
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
      data.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }        
    connection.Close();
```

Comment: What happens if there is not in fact any data returned?

Comment: *I know*, but you are posting for someone who obviously doesnt.  And `if (reader.Read()){}` will work as well as hasRows